# Using Array Map in a Javascript "Class" to Return Each Item of the Array

Tags: javascript, class, array-map

I'm trying to build some programs for fun and learning. I have the problem below:

```
function Hero(name) {
this.name = name;

this.addItem = function(item) {
    this.items = this.items || [];
    this.items.push(item);
};

// .... 

this.viewItinerary = function() {
    this.items.map(function(currItem){
        return currItem;
    });
};

}

var alex = new Hero("Alex");
alex.addItem("Sword");
alex.addItem("Shield");
console.log(alex.viewItinerary());
// returns undefined. why does it not return items in array?
```

If I replace the return statement with a console.log(currItem) it works. So why is my code returning undefined? Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: you need to do return this.items.map... but with that map that doesn´t change anything, just a return this.items would be fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because your function is not returning anything

try:

```
this.viewItinerary = function() {
    return this.items;
};
```

Also Array.map return a new array.

Comment: Thanks. I used array.map because I wanted to do something with each item in the array. My idea was that I can return the value from each index with some formatting

Comment: Well then it's fine to use Array.map but make sure you return it, also make sure you return inside map callback otherwise nothing will show up. return xx.map(item = > {  return item.innerArray.map(inside) => {return inside +1 ; }  }) Always be returning :D

Comment: You're answer is too complicated for me. What are all the arrows for ? (=>). A simple variation on my code would have helped but this is confusing me. Is it ES6 or something?

Comment: x.map(y => y + 1) is equivalent to x.map(function(y) { return y + 1}); Yes this is ES6

Comment: Ah ok, thanks for clarifying. I'm still learning old skool JS and the world is moving on :P

Answer (score 0):

`map` *returns* a new array, unless you return the result of it the return type of `viewItinery` is undefined, hence why this line

```
console.log(alex.viewItinerary());
```

logs undefined. To fix it, simply add a `return`

```
this.viewItinerary = function() {
    return this.items.map(function(currItem){
        return currItem;
    });
};
```

Comment: If I simply want to return the value of each array index, how would I do that? Is there a better way than using array.map()? Thanks

Comment: array.map has 3 arguments (item, index, array). In if u only wanted bunch of numbers (indexes) array.map((item, index) => index);